# How to set focus on specific cell in datagridview after a validation error?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, setfocus

Friends, I've windows application where I'm using a datagridview to display existing data as well add/edit data. The datagridview has a feature that on Tab/Enter key press the focus will move to next cell. If it's the last column in a row, then the focus will go to the first column of next row. Now after entering data for a cell and pressing Tab/Enter key, if there is an error message for wrongly entered data (like numeric value is not properly formatted or value is less than zero etc. etc.), after showing the error message in a message box, the focus is moving to the next cell. Is there any way that if there is an error message for a particular cell then the focus will be set to that error generating cell only, it'll not move to next cell? In dgView_CellEndEdit event I've tried to select the cell by using the code:

```
    dgView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColumnName"].Value = "0.00";
    dgView.Select();
    dgView.CurrentCell.Selected = true;
```

But it's not working. In dgView_SelectionChanged event I've used:

```
    dgView.CurrentCell = dgView[RequiredColumnIndex, RequiredRowIndex];
    dgView.BeginEdit(true);
```

This also is of no help. Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `CellValidating` event for your checks and validation. In case some of the checks fail you could prompt the error message and set <strike>e.Handled</strike>`e.Cancel= false`. This will keep the focus in the current error cell until you make the required corrections.

Comment: In dgView_SelectionChanged event, I'm setting the dgView.CurrentCell. But here it's giving following error "Operation did not succeed because the program cannot commit or quit a cell value change." .PLease suggest what to do.

Comment: I'm using visual-studio 2005 and there is no e.handled thing,it has e.Cancel

Comment: @Sukanya you are right its `e.Cancel`, for the error i think you will need to commit the cell value `grid.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)` something of that sort and then set the current cell

Comment: Before setting value for dgView.CurrentCell, I wrote the line "dgView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);" and in cellValidating event I've set e.Cancel=true;(If there is any error), yet it's giving same error as "Operation did not succeed because the program cannot commit or quit a cell value change." in SelectionChanged event.

Comment: Have you tried this `dataGridView1.Rows[currRow].Selected = true;`

Comment: Get current row as follows `int currRow = 0;
currRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;`

Comment: @User actually I've to select a cell not row.

Comment: Try this then `int currCell = 0; currCell = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;ataGridView1.Rows[currCell ].Selected = true;